# Prevent scroll of the page if pop-up is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using the jquery mobile pop up. This is inside the page. There is an image that opens this pop-up. Now how do I prevent the entire page from scrolling only if the pop-up is open and allow scrolling if the pop up is closed?

```
    <a href="#settingsPopUp" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-inline="true" data-icon="gear"><img src="settings1.jpg" alt="Settings"></a>

    <br>
    <div data-role="popup" id="settingsPopUp" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
        <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
            <h3>Location Details</h3>               
        </div>          
    </div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I have mixed **Lefois**'s solution and **Simona Adriani**'s solution. It works for me in browser and mobile phone WebView (PhoneGap + jquerymobile).

```
$(document).on('popupafteropen', '[data-role="popup"]', function(event, ui) {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden').on('touchmove', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
    });
}).on('popupafterclose', '[data-role="popup"]', function(event, ui) {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto').off('touchmove');
});
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer and should be accepted. I am using the same and this works well across all browsers on desktop as well as mobile devices.

Comment: This does not work if you still want to be able to scroll within the modal dialog.

Answer (score 4):

For me this method didn't work, it works on browser but not in Phone Gap application. So I resolve it in this way:

```
$('#Popup-id').on({
   popupbeforeposition: function(){
      $('body').on('touchmove', false);
   },
   popupafterclose: function(){
      $('body').off('touchmove'); 
  }
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It works for me! Thanks. I use `popupafteropen`and `popupafterclose`events.

Answer (score 2):

What about assigning `overflow-y: hidden;` to the element that you don't want to scroll, when the modal box is open? (usually it will be `<body>`)

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on previous answer, but there is a little mistake. Following piece of code did the trick for me:

```
$( "#mypopup" ).popup({
  afteropen: function( e) {
   $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
  },
  afterclose: function(e) {
   $('body').css('overflow','auto');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. `Either "overflow:hidden" the body`
2. `Or give a "position:fixed" to the popup so this will scroll in the viewport.`

Comment: the style makes the pop up open in the bottom right corner making it look ugly. And there is actually a drop down (that I have not pasted in the code), it is now not getting populated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use events for the pop up widget

```
$( "#settingsPopUp" ).popup({
  afteropen: function( event, ui ) {
   $('body').css({
       overflow:'hidden'
   });
  },
  afterclose: function( event, ui ) {
   $('body').css({
       overflow:'auto'
   });
  }
});
```

I think this is a dynamic solution and it will take care of your problem.